# Jstree state plugin not saving tree state

Tags: jquery, state, jstree

Adding the state plugin in Jstree is still not saving the state of the tree between page refresh or after  clicking link and going back to previous page

```
$('#myGrid').jstree({
    "types": {
       "key": {
           "icon": "Content/Images/skey.png"
       },
       "value": {
           "icon": "Content/Images/sValue.png"
       }
    },
    "state": { "key": "myTree" },
    "search": { },
    "core": {
        "check_callback":true,
        "data": [@Html.Raw(Model.JsonData)]
    },
    "plugins": ["state", "types", "search"]
```

thank you,

Comment: Did you get this sorted? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

use [set state property](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=state&f=set_state%28state%20%5B,%20callback%5D%29) from the documentation...

Comment: I tried `var jsTree = $('#myGrid').jstree(true);
            jsTree.save_state();`
but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

This works good for me on current version 3.08. 
Though I use ajax to get json data via a controller (asp.net mvc or web api) based on id, and not fetching raw html on load. I would recommend this if you can, it's cleaner and supports lazy loading.
On my setup jstree opens one node after the other until it reaches the last node I opened.

It does not play that well though if I open more than one branch of nodes.

The important thing would be that your nodes has unique id properties. Check also localStorage and see if anything is stored there.